# How do you refinish a Corian countertop?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters

The title says it all.  We have a [Corian countertop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corian).  One of the selling points of this type of counter is that it is supposedly easy to fix minor flaws in it, but there seems to be [little information on the net](https://www.google.com/search?q=refinishing+a+corian+countertop) about how to go about it.

A few years back my wife put a hot pan on it and discolored the surface.  I have tried sanding the surface down with sandpaper (start rough and then moving on to finer grits), but it only slightly improves the look.  Are their any tricks that I am missing?

Comment: We have a white Corian countertop which has similar issues. I am very interested in the resolution to this question.

Comment: the wikipedia page states "Nicks and scratches can be buffed out with a Scotch-Brite pad or orbital sander." I'd up the sanding attempt using power tools.

Comment: Have you tried bleach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some serious buffing is required.  Not just of the burn area.. but you'll need to buff the nearby surrounding areas as well.

Two options:

1. do it yourself cautious: experiment with automobile "rubbing compound" on it.. if it works on a small area, expand to the entire area.
2. do it yourself confident: sand with 800 to 1000 grit sand paper.. if it works on a small area, expand to the entire area.
3. hire someone: a corian professional

I do #3 in good times, #2 in bad.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but, just in case anyone needs to know how to refinish a Corian countertop, this is the DIY youtube vid to watch :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xiVtgcHOtE
I followed the example exactly, first using a left over as a test piece, then on our actual Corian counter top in the motorhome. It works perfectly !!!
2 things to be aware of :

1. lots of dust...rig up a vacuum to collect it as you go and wear a mask !!!
2. follow the pattern exactly, be patient, and do not skip or shorten any step.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/160895)

Answer (score -1):

I used pledge for the minor abrasions and it did help